# A combinatoric solution (closed expression) for $\sum_{k=i}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions, additive-combinatorics

I am trying to find a combinatoric solution for $\sum_{k=i}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$.

i.e. write it as a closed function (and not as a sum).

I know that in generating functions one can for example multiply the relevant function  by $\frac{1}{1-x}$. But this is relevant for combinatoric problems like identical k balls in n cells.

Is there something like that for the formula above?

Comment: There is probably no closed form for this.  Often in these kind of sums there is only a formula for the entire sum from $k=0$ to $n$, but not for partial sums.  You could probably write it in terms of a hypergeometric function, but that's just giving a name to it.

Comment: Of course there are various approximations in terms of the CDF $\Phi$ of the normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment by Jair Taylor there doesn't appear to be a closed form. The hypergeometric representation is
$$
Q(i,n,p)=\sum_{k=i}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = (1-p)^{n-i}p^i \binom{n}{i}\; _2F_1 \left(1,i-n;i+1;\frac{p}{p-1}\right)
$$
and the generating function is very similar
$$
\sum_{k=i}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}x^{k} = (1-p)^{n-i}p^i x^i \binom{n}{i} \;_2F_1 \left(1,i-n;i+1;\frac{p x}{p-1}\right)
$$
if you want the generating function over all possible values of $i$, Mathematica claims there is a recursion relation for
$$
F(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n Q(i,n,p)x^i
$$
then if we define a function $y_k(x,p,n)$ where
$$
y_0 = 0 \\
y_1 = \left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)^n \\
y_2 = y_1 + \left(y_1-1\right)x
%(n-k)p x^2 y_k - x(1+k-p-2kp+np-kpx+npx)y_{k+1} + (1 + k -p-kp + x + kx-px-2kpx+npx)y_{k+2}+(1+k)(p-1)y_{k+3}=0
$$
and in general
$$
y_{k+3} = a(k) y_{k+2} + b(k) y_{k+1} + c(k) y_{k}
$$
with
$$
a(k) = -\frac{(1 + k -p-kp + x + kx-px-2kpx+npx)}{(1+k)(p-1)}\\
b(k) = \frac{x(1+k-p-2kp+np-kpx+npx)}{(1+k)(p-1)} \\
c(k) = -\frac{(n-k)p x^2}{(1+k)(p-1)}
$$
then
$$
F(x) = (1-p)^ny_{n+1}
$$